# How to check if iframe is visible from within the iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I develop a widget that is expected to run on a partner's site as an iFrame.  The iFrame is served up via a different domain than the parent's domain, so I cannot explicitly access their DOM.

The end-user can expand/collapse our widget using a button on the parent page.  The parent page does not alert us when this happens or give us any way to tell the current status.

So I'm looking to see if there is some way around this by detecting from within our iFrame if the document is hidden. We use this information to determine if we need to send notifications to the end-user if our widget is hidden.

I've tried some things, like hookinh into the `visibilitychange` event, but it doesn't fire.  I've also tried doing a hacky thing like getting the computed style of `document.body` but it doesn't seem to change based on whether the iFrame is hidden or not.

Comment: Intersection observer is api that should tell you if an element is visible. If you hook body to it is should do the trick. Other than that, you can do in only in frames that are of same origin.

Comment: well if you can have a script running on their page it is possible, without that, you are out of luck.

Comment: Thanks Akxe for the idea! I gave that a shot, but for some reason it was only firing once.  However reading through the docs helped me realize that `getBoundingClientRect()` and checking `if(height === 0)` will do the trick for what I need.

Comment: @Akxe - Intersection observer is a good solution (the only one that worked for me so far), could you please submit an answer with a link to MDN documentation about it and a simple explanation on what it does ?

Answer (score 0):

@andrew it will working only if its hidden by display: none. Visibility: hidden will report the proper width height values. Intersection observer will report true even if its hidden by display: none or visibility: hidden but it is in the viewport.